# Not able to display the output after regular interval using sleep

Tags: c, unix, gcc, sleep

Following is the code snippet.

```
int main()
{
int i =0;
    while (i++ < 5)
    {
        // Do some heavy processing
        printf("i = %d\n", i);
        sleep(1);
    }
}
```

The heavy processing part is doing its part every 1 second. 
I want to display 'i' after 1 s as well but its displaying the entire output after its done. I know using a while is not a very elegant way to do this, but it seemed easier. Which is the optimal way of achieving this?

I am running the code in unix, gcc complier

Comment: It is not displaying the output after every second, but after it comes out of while

Comment: Try #include <stdio.h>, then use fflush(stdout);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to flush stdout; you can use fflush(3) to do so:

```
fflush(stdout);
```

You could also disable buffering entirely on stdout:

```
setbuf(stdout, NULL);
```

Answer (score 1):

in windows:

```
 #include <windows.h>

    Sleep(number of milliseconds);
```

or use this in basic C:

```
 #include <unistd.h>

    unsigned sleep(unsigned seconds);
```

for unix:

```
sleep n  //n is the number of sec
```

Comment: I am running the code in unix, gcc complier. This does not work

Answer (score 0):

sleep takes its parameters in milliseconds so you have to pass sleep(10000);

if some other code is processing and after the processing is done you have to display the value, rather every one second you may keep a monitor that is updated by that code and then display accordingly. sounds like Producer Consumer problem , might help if you give that a look

Comment: Sleep(windows.h) takes its parameter in miliseconds.sleep takes its parameter in seconds.

Answer (score 0):

You need to print unbuffered, the simple way to do that is to fflush stdout after the printf

```
fflush(stdout);
```

or print to stderr.

```
fprintf(stderr, "i = %d\n", i);
```

Also it's important to note that this is not printing every 1 second but every 1 second + duration of heavy processing which may vary from loop to loop. To improve this you should(psuedocode not real code).

```
int i = 0;
for(i=0; i < 5; i++)
{
    measure before time
    do stuff
    measure after time 
    sleep( 1 - (after -before in seconds)) or better usleep( 1000000 - (after - before in microseconds))
    print something
}
```

This method allows you to print something about every 1 second (as long as doing stuff takes a bit less then 1 second)

If this is linux specific I would recomend using [clock_gettime](http://linux.die.net/man/3/clock_gettime) with CLOCK_MONOTONIC to measure time.